# Not able to copy values from two tags to another in XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, altova

1. This is my input data. It contains a number of other fields also, but i have removed them:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <tables>
    <table>
     <row>
       <JOURNAL_DATE></JOURNAL_DATE>
       <TRANSACTION_DATE>2016-08-15T00:00:00-04:00</TRANSACTION_DATE>
       <TRANSACTION_TIME>11:52:18.005</TRANSACTION_TIME>
     </row>
   <table>
   </tables>
   ```
2. I want a output like this, where the journal_date is having date value of transaction_date and time of transaction_time:

   ```
   <JOURNAL_DATE>2016-08-15 11:52:18.005</JOURNAL_DATE>
   <TRANSACTION_DATE>2016-08-15T00:00:00-04:00</TRANSACTION_DATE>
   <TRANSACTION_TIME>11:52:18.005</TRANSACTION_TIME>
   ```
3. I am using the following XSL code, what more changes do i need to do? I am a newbie.

   ```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <!--Suryanshu For adding required date format -->

   <xsl:template match="JOURNAL_DATE">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:call-template name="formatdate">
       <xsl:with-param name="datestr" select="."/>
     </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>


   <xsl:template name="formatdate">
   <xsl:param name="datestr"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="substring($datestr,1,10)"/>
   </xsl:template>

   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```

What more changes do i need to do, so that the transaction time is added in journal date tag.

Answer (score 0):

To pass the correct value to your `formatdate` template, you need to reference the transaction date like so...

```
<xsl:with-param name="datestr" select="../TRANSACTION_DATE"/>
```

Where, `..` selects the parent element `row`.

Try this XSLT template

```
<xsl:template match="JOURNAL_DATE">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:call-template name="formatdate">
    <xsl:with-param name="datestr" select="../TRANSACTION_DATE"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="../TRANSACTION_TIME" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```